# How customize magento 2 menu

Tags: magento2

I was wondering how to customize the magento 2 menu as shown below.. Is someone have a clear idea about that ?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the some class and i have tried may be help you

Go to your theme `default.xml` file

First move the top search bar

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

second apply css :-

This class block block-search apply `float :left`

And check search bar move the after logo.

Second part put the code :-

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart" />
```

And apply css your design and add your new button after  `catalog.topnav` class and apply the some css your design

[image]

And other you put this code in your `default.xml` file.

```
<move element="authorization-link-login" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart"/>
```

And apply the css `li.authorization-link {float:right}` and check

And finally all content are move and you set the design wise..

May be help you

let me know any query..

Hey this is my Default XML

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo"/>
        <container name="header.search.links.wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="search-links-wrap" >
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.custom.top.links" template="Magento_Theme::header/custom-top-links.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.account.links.icon" template="Magento_Theme::header/account-links-icon.phtml"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true" />
</body>
```

[image]

How to achieve this

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but how move sign in saign up next to mini cart

Comment: check this image https://prnt.sc/ru0ykg and put this code <move element="authorization-link-login" destination="header-wrapper" before="minicart"/> and apply this class li.authorization-link {float:right}

Comment: and check my update answer..

Comment: Hi I updated the question do u have any idea how to achieve this

Comment: This answer helpful so Please accept and upvote answer because helpful another community...